# Array pointer while loop input

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, while-loop

I am trying to write a program to check for duplicate input from a programmable handheld barcode scanner, I am programming it to be able to scan 2000 barcodes.

I am new to c Programming, I am trying to take an input and put it into the array and increase the pointer to the next with every loop.

**Example:** `int Array [10];`

I want to `scanf()` into Array *location 0* on the first loop then increment by 1 location to *location 2* etc every time the while loops runs. Please help, your help is much appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    int i,j,k=1,arr[2000],ArrSize=2000;

    //Welcome message
    printf("Welcome to Yamato Transport (S) Pte. Ltd.\n");
    printf("Barcode checker Ver 1.0\n");

    while (k>=2000,k++)
    {
        //Scanner Input
        for(i=0;i<ArrSize;i++)
        {
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
        }

        //Duplicate Logic
        printf("Duplicate Barcodes: ");
        for(i=0; i<ArrSize; i++)
        {
            for(j=i+1;j<ArrSize;j++)
            {
            if(arr[i]==arr[j])
            {
            printf("%d\n",arr[i]);
            }
        }
        }
        //Remove single duplicate

        //Clear Screen

    }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a sample input/ouput for your program? Quetions on Stack Oveflow are more successful if users can copy and paste your code, then test it to reproduce the difficulties you are encountering. Read here about how to make a [mcve].

Comment: I don't have an example because I am not sure how to go about the "scanner input "portion. what would help is a tutorial on how I can do the following: "take an input and put it into the array and increase the pointer to the next with every loop".

I can't find a tutorial anywhere online to help solve this problem.

Comment: So basically what I need it to do, Scan into array -> check for duplicates, prompt if any -> delete duplicate -> repeat up to 2000 times.

My problem is how do I create a function that reads the input and put it into the array in a different pointer every loop and pass the function over to the duplicate checker which will prompt for duplicate barcodes and lastly delete the duplicate so it will not prompt user again that a duplicate has been scanned.

Answer (score 2):

The first problem with your code is this:

```
int i,j,k=1,...

...

while (k>=2000,k++)
        ^^^^^^
        ups...
```

This will give the warning "left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect" which actually means that the line is the same as:

```
while (k++)
```

That will keep looping until you have integer overflow (which is undefined behavior). So you don't want to do that.

Since you initialize `k` to 1, I assume that you wanted to do:

```
while (k++ < 2000)
```

Now let's assume that you want:

```
while (k++ < 2000)  // Will loop approx 2000 times
{
    //Scanner Input
    for(i=0; i< ArrSize; i++)  // Will loop 2000 times
    {
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
    }
```

So in the end your program calls `scanf` 2000 x 2000 = 4.000.000 times. Is that what you want? The purpose of the outer `while` is unclear.

Your program first reads 2000 integers and afterwards it seems you want to remove duplicates. That's a bad approach as you may end you doing a lot of memory move whenever you need to remove a duplicate element from the array.

A better approach is to check whether a newly scanned value is a duplicate **before** inserting it in the array. That could look something like:

```
    for(i=0; i < ArrSize; )
    {
        int tmp;
        if (scanf("%d", &tmp) != 1) 
        {
            // Input error
            exit(1);
        }

        // Check if tmp is already in the array
        int duplicate = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j)
        {
            if (tmp == arr[j])
            {
                duplicate = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (duplicate)
        {
            printf("dup found\n");
        }
        else
        {
            arr[i] = tmp;
            ++i;
        }
    }
```

This should give you `ArrSize` unique elements.

Notice: In order to check if something is a duplicate, you'll need to scan through the array from start to the current number of elements. To improve performance you could consider another approach, e.g. a sorted tree, hash tables, etc so that check for duplicates can be done much faster. This gets more important as the number of array elements increase.

Comment: thank you for spoting that error, I just need it to run up to 2000 times/scans.

Comment: Real-world would implement it as a hash-table for lookup efficiency, but for your purposes with a max of 2000, iterating is fine. (but there are much more efficient ways to do it)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Agree, for "small" amount of data the simple array approach can be ok and even preferred because it's simple to code. For large amount of data, e.g. 10.000.000 elements, the simple array approach is just a no-go.

Comment: Yep, sorry for the lack of specificity, it was clear from your answer you were pointing that out, the suggestion of the hash-table was for the Questioner's benefit.

Comment: So basically the while loop is for loop through each scan, 1 scan from barcode reader = 1 loop. within the loop it takes the input and stores it in the array then checks for duplicates(prompts user if any duplicates) then deletes the duplicate if not it would prompt user that there is a duplicate on the next instance of the loop.

Comment: basically right now my code takes all the input first then checks for duplicates, I want it to just take 1 input each time it goes through the loop then check for duplicates then lastly delete the duplicate so it does not prompt user that there is still a duplicate on the next scan/loop

1 loop = 1 scan.

Answer (score 0):

So half the problem is solved, I am still not sure how do I increase the pointer to the next position so on the next loop it will store another barcode number which will then be passed to the duplicate checker for checking then repeat the loop for the next scan.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {

int i,j,k=1,arr[2000],counter=1;
//Welcome message
  printf("Welcome to Yamato Transport (S) Pte. Ltd.\n");
  printf("Barcode checker Ver 1.0\n");

  while (k++ < 2000)  // Will loop approx 2000 times
{
//Scanner Input
printf("Scan barcode\n");
for(i=0; i< counter; i++)  // Will loop 1 time
{
    scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
}

  //check for duplicates
  for(i=0; i < counter; )
    {
        int tmp;
        if (scanf("%d", &tmp) != 1) 
        {
            // Input error
            exit(1);
        }

        // Check if tmp is already in the array
        int duplicate = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j)
        {
            if (tmp == arr[j])
            {
                duplicate = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (duplicate)
        {
            printf("Duplicate Barcode\n");
        }
        else
        {
            arr[i] = tmp;
            ++i;
        }
    }

  }
  return 0;
}
```